# Get variable with PHP from JSON

Tags: php, json, decode

I have been scratching my head with this one and wonder if anybody would be kind enough to give me a pointer. I am extracting some data as a variable from JSON to PHP, and I can do this no problem when there are nested nodes - IF the node is a text but not if the node is a number. I am using json_decode
THIS IS NOT THE SAME AS How do I extract data from JSON with PHP?

This is ok

```
$get_temp = $jsonobj->main->temp;
```

This is not working

```
$get_weather = $jsonobj->main->0->weather;
```

So my question is how do I target the node when it is a number? 
Thanks

Comment: can you please add json

Comment: @Dean yes, it is. read the fine answer, there are whole **sections** dedicated to accessing content inside the decoded json.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```
$get_weather = $jsonobj->main[0]->weather;
```

Comment: @MagnusEriksson - Modified My Answer.

Answer (score 4):

Probabily you have an array into main node.. so you can get its value with an index like this:

```
$get_weather = $jsonobj->main[0]->weather;
```

Where `0` is the index that you want to get

Comment: Thank you. Brilliant :-) I shall accept answer in a few minutes when it lets me

Comment: Glad to help you @Dean !

Answer (score 3):

```
$get_weather = $jsonobj->main[$x]->weather;
```

**$x** would be the index